# Tufte-LaTeX clobbers my list of theorems

Tags: table-of-contents, tufte

when using the "article" document class I can make a "List of Theorems" like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\listoftheorems

\begin{theorem}
A deep theorem.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

However, if I switch to "tufte-book" document class, my list of theorems is no longer generated. How do I get it back? Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a `tocdepth` issue. According to lines 67-68 of [`tufte-book.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tufte-latex/tufte-book.cls)

```
% Only show the chapter titles in the table of contents
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}
```

which also affects `\listoftheorems`

You can counter it (pun intended!) by using, for example

```
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
```

as in the MWE below

```
%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\listoftheorems

\begin{theorem}
A deep theorem.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

You can read more about `tocdepth` here, for example: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Document_Structure